# MongoDB aggregate pipeline created by C# Driver optimisation

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

- Description:

*I have a C# code that creates an aggregation pipeline based on incoming request and then executes it on MongoDB.*

Basically, it starts with a "base collection" on which the aggregation will be performed which is filtered with *$match* stage, followed by the variable number (up to 6) of *$unionWith* stages for other collections (each has its own *$match* stage, ***they might be different for each of the collection***, but in the example they are identical), *$sort*, *$skip* and *$limit* stages.

Example pipeline that is generated by C# looks like the following:

```
db.Recipe.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "entity.metadata.tenantIdentifier": "test"
    }
  },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "ChoiceGroup",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "entity.metadata.tenantIdentifier": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
   {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "Instruction",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "entity.metadata.tenantIdentifier": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "entity.spec.mainName": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
])
```

- Problem:

It takes AGES (~40/50 seconds) on a relatively small data sets, each of mentioned collections with about 50k documents).

I think it might be related to indexes not being used with the *$sort* stage, because when I remove this stage, results are returned almost right away. For each of possible collections that might be 'unioned-with', I created an index to support that sorting:

*entity.spec.mainName_1 (asc)*

Other indexes in the collections are the following:

**id* (ASC)*

*entity.metadata.tenantIdentifier_1_entity.metadata.identifier_1 (unique, compound)*

*entity.metadata.tenantIdentifier_1_entity.spec.subcategoryIdentifier_1 (compound)*

- Might be useful:

Example document structure that can can be found in the queried collections:

```
{
    _id: 'tenants/123xyz',
    entity: {
        apiVersion: 'serv/v1',
        kind: 'Recipe',
        metadata: {
            identifier: 'Rec.001',
            resourceVersion: '1',
            uid: 'aa63cb93-e08b-45f6-9c62-f138cd069f45',
            tenantIdentifier: 'testTenant'
        },
        spec: {
            subcategoryIdentifier: 'identifier',
            courseIdentifier: 'identifier',
            portions: {
                standardPortion: {
                    cookTime: '00:05:00',
                    ingredients: [
                        {
                            ingredientId: 1,
                            ingredientAmount: {
                                portionAmount: {
                                    portionTypeIdentifier: 'PTI.001',
                                    amount: '10.0'
                                }
                            },
                            isMinor: false
                        }
                    ],
                    friendlyName: 'Standard',
                    description: 'test desc',
                    hiddenFromMenus: true
                }
            },
            mainName: 'Test MainName'
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips regarding optimisation of that pipeline would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try running the query with "explain" using the "allPlansExection" option to see what indexes it considered?